# Is it possible to detect if you are on the synchronous side of an async method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I am trying to develop a context system for a web application which will propagate data along the logical flow of control. This is similar to AsyncLocal stack described [enter link description here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).

Originally, I was simply using the LogicalCallContext to do this, but this runs into issues with ASP.NET thread agility. To counter this, I have implemented a hybrid system that uses both the logical call context and HttpContext.Items. With this system, we keep the two contexts in sync (assuming both are available), and trust the logical call context unless it is missing and there is something in HttpContext.Items.

This works in almost all cases, but can run into trouble in the first half of an async method that is called from a synchronous method where we are on the request thread but in a different logical call context. Here's an example:

```
// in BeginRequest
MyContext.Push("BeginRequest");

public ActionResult SomeAction() 
{
    // sometimes Asp.NET does a thread switch between begin request and the action
    // in that case, we have:
    // Logical: null
    // HttpContext:  "BeginRequest"

    var result = this.DoSomethingAsync().Result;

    // Here we have
    // Logical: null
    // THIS IS WRONG: the logical context was correctly restored by async magic, but we
    // corrupted the HttpContext. Since we lost the logical call context, we can't use that
    // HttpContext: "DoSomethingAsync" -> "BeginRequest"
}

private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    // right now we're on the request thread, so we still have HttpContext but
    // because we have a logical call context 
    // I would like to detect when the code is in THIS STATE
    MyContext.Push("DoSomethingAsync");

    // Here we have
    // Logical: "DoSomethingAsync" -> "BeginRequest"
    // HttpContext: "DoSomethingAsync" -> "BeginRequest"

    // because this method does ConfigureAwait(false), on the other side of await
    // you won't have the context
    await ComputeSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Here we have
    // Logical: "DoSomethingAsync" -> "BeginRequest"
    // HttpContext: null    

    MyContext.Pop();

    // Here we have
    // Logical: "BeginRequest"
    // HttpContext: null    
}
```

Is there any way to detect this state? Is there another way to get a consistent logical context flow in ASP.NET/.NET 4.5?

Comment: It appears, the problem is introduced in the first place by `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Otherwise, the context would be flowed correctly. Why do you have to use it, only to avoid deadlocks like with `this.DoSomethingAsync().Result`? Can you not use async "all the way down"?

Comment: @Noseratio: yes, that's the issue, but I can't change this. My context needs to work throughout an entire set of web applications where developers use different asynchrony styles, including this one (which is common when you need to call an async-only API from an otherwise synchronous flow.

Comment: Hmm, if some code is outside your control, you wouldn't be able to plug in the `LogicalCallContext` state retrieval logic there anyway. OTOH, in the code you *do* have control over, just don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` and don't mix `await` with blocking `Wait/Result`, everything will be propagated.

Comment: I recommend that you try to get a reproducible issue where the `LogicalCallContext` is failing to propagate, and see if you can find a fix for that.